# Julia - absolute value of an array

Tags: math, julia, linear-algebra, absolute-value

I want to get the absolute value of the following array:

```
x = [1.1 -22.3 3.01, -1]
```

i.e.: I want an output of the type: `x2 = [1.1 22.3 3.01 1]`
However when I type:

```
abs(x)
```

I get an error:

```
ERROR: MethodError: no method matching abs(::Array{Float64,2})
Closest candidates are:
  abs(::Pkg.Resolve.MaxSum.FieldValues.FieldValue) at /Users/vagrant/worker/juliapro-release-osx1011-0_6/build/tmp_julia/Julia-1.0.app/Contents/Resources/julia/share/julia/stdlib/v1.0/Pkg/src/resolve/FieldValues.jl:67
  abs(::Pkg.Resolve.VersionWeights.VersionWeight) at /Users/vagrant/worker/juliapro-release-osx1011-0_6/build/tmp_julia/Julia-1.0.app/Contents/Resources/julia/share/julia/stdlib/v1.0/Pkg/src/resolve/VersionWeights.jl:40
  abs(::Missing) at missing.jl:79
  ...
Stacktrace:
 [1] top-level scope at none:0
```

Comment: Are you expecting `abs` to return an array where all the elements are their absolute value?

Comment: Thank you for your comment @George. Yes! i want a result of the type `x2 = [1.1 22.3 3.01]`. I'll update the question in that sense

Comment: Looking at the docs I guess `for i = 0:length(x) x[i] = abs(x[i]) end` would work? Or resizing a new `x2` and assigning to that using the same for loop.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Julia does not automatically apply scalar functions, like `abs`, to elements of an array. You should instead tell Julia this is what you want, and broadcast the scalar function `abs` over your array, see https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/arrays/#Broadcasting-1. This can be done as

```
julia> x = [1.1, -22.3, 3.01, -1];

julia> broadcast(abs, x)
4-element Array{Float64,1}:
  1.1 
 22.3 
  3.01
  1.0
```

or you can use "dot-notation", which is more ideomatic:

```
julia> abs.(x)
4-element Array{Float64,1}:
  1.1 
 22.3 
  3.01
  1.0
```

Comment: The [`@.` macro](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/arrays/#Base.Broadcast.@__dot__) is very handy, especially for more more complex cases. `@. x2 = abs(x)`