# Convert a vector of positive/negative elements to all positive elements in Julia?

Tags: matrix, julia, linear-algebra, numerical-methods

Given a one dimensional vector in Julia with positive and negative entries, like A=[1;-3;5;-7], is there any function or command that can alter this vector so that its elements all become positive, so that it becomes A=[1;3;5;7]?

Comment: Have a look at: [Julia - absolute value of an array](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53943507/10488504)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Julia - absolute value of an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53943507/julia-absolute-value-of-an-array)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Vectorize over `abs`:

```
julia> abs.(A)
4-element Vector{Int64}:
 1
 3
 5
 7
```

Any function in Julia can work over an array by just appending a dot `.` to its name.

Comment: Without allocation, the same can be achieved with `map!(abs, A, A)`

Comment: A comment by @DNF offers a neater looking version: `A .= abs.(A)`